# An upper bound on the Jordan condition number of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory

The *Jordan condition number* of a matrix $A$ is defined to be $\min_{V}\kappa(V)$, where $V$ ranges over complex matrices that satisfy $A = VJV^{-1}$ for $J$ being the unique Jordan normal form matrix of $A$. ($\kappa$ is the condition number, i.e., $\kappa(V) = \|V\|\|V^{-1}\|$).

Clearly, if $A$ is normal then the Jordan condition number of $A$ is $1$, and for arbitrary matrices it is unbounded.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with *bounded* integer entries. Say, even, a 0-1 matrix.
How large can the Jordan condition number of $A$ be? Can it be larger, than, say $n^{n}$? As, e.g., answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260702/upper-bounds-on-the-condition-number-of-the-eigenvector-matrix), this is not true in general. However, maybe the integrality helps. For example, if an invertible matrix $X$ has integer values between $[-n,n]$, its condition number cannot be larger than $2n^{n}$.

Comment: The min in defining $V$ is over complex matrices?

Comment: @YCor Yes, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Why is the Jordan condition number unbounded?